# Java Hotswap with Eclipses and Remote Debugging on Local Machine

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, remote-debugging, hotswap

I'm trying to find out how to enable hotswapping of code while debugging with my build system and am coming up dry.

I've got an Ant build with a debug target like so:

```
<target name="debug_dev" depends="compile"
    description="Runs development version with the debugger.">
    <java classname="applets.TabHandler" fork="true" dir="build">
      <jvmarg value="-Xdebug" />
      <jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000" />
        <classpath refid="compile_classpath" />
    </java>
</target>
```

I then use the remote debugging option in Eclipse to connect to port 8000. Debugging works fine, but I cannot edit code like I was able to before I was using Ant. I know that it is possible to get hotswapping working with JBoss, Tomcat, and other situations, but I am just running my program locally with a JVM call, as you can see from above.

Does anyone know if this is possible with my setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Ant hotswap works rather well. There is no need to do it in Eclipse.

http://code.google.com/p/hotswap/

Comment: I will try this in my project very shortly. Thanks for the heads-up. For a while I was running the debug from Ant, but I went back to using the Eclipse debug launch, so I don't know if this will mesh with that way of debugging. I will go to Ant debug launches if it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried it out today, and it works. I trigger the debug instance of the JVM via an Ant task. I then trigger the Eclipse debug client via a remote debug configuration, aimed at the same port number used in the debug Ant task. I then made changes, and triggered hotswap via an Ant task, based on the example provided on the hotswap project page that andersonbd1 posted above. Excellent!   Unfortunately, I do receive an error when I run it, when the hotswap task is called: "BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\myself\workspace\my_project\build.xml:758: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"

Comment: This solution was important for me because I do have a separate compile process in Ant from Eclipse's built in, thus removing Eclipse's hotswap functionality. This hotswap Ant task is precisely what I needed. If only I could trigger Eclipse's debug client from Ant, I could get the debug launch down to one click to trigger the Ant task, and another click when I want to compile & hotswap.

Comment: I'm also getting Connection refused issue, did anyone find a root cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

Get Ant out of your debugging workflow. Use Ant for packaging final product or continuous integration, but for iterative development and debugging, compile and run code directly from Eclipse. You will get hotswapping, etc. that way.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks. I'll have to configure Eclipse to run my Ant compile target properly, but that seems fine. It seemed cleaner to abandon Eclipse's build related functionality wherever I could. If this is the only way to get hotswapping then I will go for it.

Comment: Any time you try to wedge Ant or Maven into Eclipse iterative dev and debugging workflow you are defeating optimizations built into Eclipse and its various plugins to make those workflows as fast as possible. Don't fight your tools. Let them make your life easier.