# How to keep an object in memory during development

Tags: java, jvm

My program has the following structure:

```
void main (String[] args) {
   Object largeObject = longInitialization();
   interestingLogic(largeObject);
}
```

The longInitialization code never changes during development. BUt whenever I change the interestingLogic, I have to run the program again and wait for the longInitialization to complete.

Unfortunately I cannot serialize largeObject because it is not Serializable and I don't have the code to it.

Is there a trick by which I can save the initialization time? Maybe, in some way save the state of the JVM just after initialization, and then always start from that state?

Comment: Can you hot deploy code while debugging.  For the Oracle JVM that might be enough to be useful.

Comment: Well, you can put the largeObject into a ArrayList and serialize the array list.

Comment: @sk2212 that will not help

Comment: 5 answers for you and no reply or comment from your side. Was this a completely waste of time?

Comment: @Guido The answers look good, but I didn't have time to try them in practice yet. Please be patient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make little modification of code:

```
main(){
    Object largeObject = longInitialization();
    boolean debug = true;
    while(debug){
        interestingLogic(largeObject);
    }
}
```

now run program in debug mode. Set breakpoint at `interestingLogic` call and use code hotswap debug mode in IDE. read more about hotswap in Eclipe: [Java Hotswap with Eclipses and Remote Debugging on Local Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476317/java-hotswap-with-eclipses-and-remote-debugging-on-local-machine)

//Edit:

One more option. Just write mock of `largeObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a new object to call interestingLogic(largeObject). You can make changes to the new object while the driver program is waiting for user input.

```
void main (String[] args) {
Object largeObject = longInitialization();

 boolean anotherTry = true;
 String answer = "";
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 while (anotherTry) {
        Object newobject = NewObject();
        newobject.interestingLogic(largeObject).
        System.out.print("Run Again Y/N");
        answer = input.nextLine();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            anotherTry = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also a good option, although it is a little longer.

Answer (score 0):

If the large object is not needed immediately, you could decorate it with a "lazy initializing" wrapper, and invoke the "longInitialization" just before you want to access it.

A second solution could be "cloning" it by marshalling/unmarshalling it to an xml file

Answer (score 0):

Because you said "...cannot serialize largeObject..." there is no way to persist an object across JVM lifetimes (since you don't have the source).  But, you have code that initializes/uses the largeOject. Create a serializable debugLargeObject that acts like the real largeObject and use debugLargeObject during development.

Answer (score 0):

Not without a lot of work. You need a minor refactor, as shown by Guido, then you need to reload the NewObject class each time through the loop (or whatever). In other words, your VM needs to be able to remove the NewObject class, then reload it, each time you change the code.

There are commercial products which do this (see JRebel, for example). You can roll your own (see this StackOverflow topic: [Unloading classes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java)). You can hotswap, if you're very careful about your interestingLogic.  But ultimately, you need to swap out that class somehow.